# Missing Visual Basic tab Microsoft Excel

Tags: ms-office

Brand new install of 365 Excel/Word/Etc. I'm trying to open the Visual Basic editor that is supposed to be on the Developers tab; however, the option isn't there.

[Enable Developer Tab](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/find-help-on-using-the-visual-basic-editor-61404b99-84af-4aa3-b1ca-465bc4f45432)

This is how my developer tab looks, and it looks like there should be some more options to the left of the "Add-Ins" button. Any idea where it went?
[image: Missing Visual Basic]

[This is how it should be...](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2016.php)

Comment: You are comparing the Windows version of "MS Excel 2016" with the "Office 365" version on macOS.

Comment: Okay, even so. Shouldn't there be a Visual Basic editor there somewhere? In the Preferences, where I go to enable the Developer Tab, the option for `Visual Basic` is shown.

Comment: Hi. In your about excel, what version and what licensing model are you using. VBA has great dev notes, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac

Comment: You can't use Tools >> Macro >> Visual Basic Editor?